# Конвертация PDF в WORD

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word

Что есть

- сервер + PHP,
- файл/документ PDF
  Какими библиотеками/скриптами/модулями сконвертировать этот файл/документ PDF в WORD?  Интересует минимальное описание используемых методов.

Comment: В гугле пробовали искать? https://github.com/aspose-pdf/Aspose.PDF-for-Java/tree/master/Plugins/Aspose_Pdf_Java_for_PHP